# Adding a Grand Total Line to a dataframe to CSV output

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file that has the following data:

| Product | Date | Company | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2/1/2021 | 1230 | 24314 |
| A | 2/1/2021 | 1224 | 14222 |
| B | 2/1/2021 | 1442 | 24141 |
| B | 2/1/2021 | 1424 | 54352 |
| B | 2/1/2021 | 4919 | 12213 |
| C | 2/1/2021 | 2312 | 43536 |
| C | 2/1/2021 | 2322 | 24241 |
| D | 2/1/2021 | 1131 | 34532 |
| E | 2/1/2021 | 1414 | 45645 |
| E | 2/1/2021 | 7674 | 21321 |

I have a script that filters on each **Product** and subsequently creates a CSV for that product:

```
report_import = (r’path\product_report.csv")

report_df = pd.read_csv(report_import, sep='\t',encoding="utf16")

# Get all available products
products = set(report_df[‘Product’])

for product in products:
    #Perform a filter for each product
    temp_df = report_df[report_df[‘Product’] == product]
    temp_df.to_csv(r"path\" + product + ".csv", index=False)
```

How would I add a grand total row that shows the total sum of the **Revenue** column?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the line

```
temp_df['grand total'] = temp_df.Revenue.sum()
```

Comment: This will add a column grand total. Question is to get the total as a row.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this answer. You need to get the sum of the revenue column to the end of the data frame as a new raw.

```
def test_new():
 df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\myfolder\prodc.csv')     
 df.loc['Total','Revenue']= df['Revenue'].sum()
 print(df)
```

test_new()

[image: Result]

Comment: Is it possible to have the grand total line not a part of the index?

Comment: @MaxLee you mean as a separate line ?